# Passing props to material-ui button wrapped by styled-components with Typescript

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styled-components

I've created react project with typescript template and I have styled material-ui Button component with **styled** method from **styled-components** library like below:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Button, {ButtonProps} from "@material-ui/core/Button";

type StyledButtonProps = ButtonProps & { primary?: boolean }


const styledButton = styled(Button)`
  background-color: ${(props: StyledButtonProps) => props.primary ? "palevioletred" : "white"};
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.11), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  padding: 7px 14px;

  &:hover {
    background-color: aqua;
  }

  & .MuiButton-label {
    color: #070303;
  }
` as React.ComponentType<StyledButtonProps>

export default styledButton;
```

I'm trying to pass boolean value primary which determine color. It generally works but there  is an warning message when I try to use this Styled button like below:

```
<StyledButton primary={true}>Styled Buton</StyledButton>
```

The warning message is:
[image]

Why is that? How can I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styled-components tries to pass `primary=true` to the DOM but DOM only accept string value `primary="true"`. Therefore, it warns you to change the `true` to `"true"` so it can be rendered to DOM successfully.

If we change `primary={true}` to `primary="true"`, the primary attributes will be displayed on DOM like below:
[image]

---

But I think you don't want `primary` to be rendered to DOM so

**Use Transient props to dismiss the warning:**

The **dollar sign ($)** prefix helps styled-components to avoid passing that property to DOM. [Read this for details](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#transient-props)

```js
<StyledButton $primary={true}>Styled Buton</StyledButton>

...

background-color: ${(props: StyledButtonProps) =>
    props.$primary ? "palevioletred" : "white"};
...
```

Here is the [codesandbox for demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-goodall-oqii6?file=/src/StyledButton.tsx).